# compute $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta}):\mathbb{Q}] $ where $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ is irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to compute  $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta}):\mathbb{Q}] $ where $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ is irrational

The strategy here is compute the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta})$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ since $e$ is transcendental i guess $e^{i\theta}$ is also a transcendental thus it seems to me that $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta})$ has infinite basis, am I right? [No]

How can I prove rigorously?

---

\begin{align}
\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\theta}) = \mathbb{Q}(i\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)) 
\end{align}
Then how can we obtain the expression about $\mathbb{Q}(i\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)) $?

Comment: Don't overlook the case of $\theta=2\pi$.

Comment: What if $e^{i\theta}=3/5+4i/5$?